# S3: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a thumbnail and so many other buckets in S3. While uploading an image I found the following error message. I am able to access all other buckets.

```
ERROR AwsServiceImpl:158 - Error Message:    Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: B67F17176759690A)
ERROR AwsServiceImpl:159 - HTTP Status Code: 403
ERROR AwsServiceImpl:160 - AWS Error Code:   AccessDenied
ERROR AwsServiceImpl:161 - Error Type:       Client
ERROR AwsServiceImpl:162 - Request ID:       B67F17176759690A
```

Can anybody point out the reason behind the message?

Comment: Can you supply more information? For example, what is the command you are using that generated this error? Do you have Bucket Policy on the bucket? What S3 permissions are on the IAM User that made the call? Feel free to Edit your question to add details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says `Access Denied`.

This means that you do not have sufficient permission to access the object in S3.

Permissions can be added either as a **Bucket Policy** or directly on the **IAM User**.

Answer (score 0):

In backet policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1405592139000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::NAME OF YOUR BUCKET/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::NAME OF YOUR BUCKET"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1405592139000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::NAME OF YOUR BUCKET/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::NAME OF YOUR BUCKET"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```